# Passing an object keys value to array

Tags: php, arrays, object

Language : PHP,
Framework : Laravel,

I have a collection of array.
I want to create a new array for each key and push all the variables to the array.
I have done the following code which looks ugly.
Is there some better way to do this.

I have created an new array for key using foreach loop and then passed the value to the array again using foreach loop.

```
$resultLabels = [];
foreach ($results as $result) {
    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        array_push($resultLabels,'ward_no ' .$value);
    }
}

foreach ($results as $result){
    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        if($key != 'ward_no'){
            array_push($arrays[$key],$value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: If it works and you want your code reviewed then [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place to post this.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another nested loop. Have a look here:

```php
$resultLabels = [];

foreach ($results as $result){
    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        array_push($resultLabels,'ward_no ' .$value);
        if($key != 'ward_no'){
            array_push($arrays[$key],$value);
        }
    }
}
```